# Custom navigation / menu output (walker?)

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I'm trying to implement a responsive jQuery navigation but I need to extend the default output of the WP menu. I believe I need to use a custom walker but honestly, I don't know how to get it to work for me; I just don't know how to get the output I need from it.

I need to wrap any pages that have children with a span and remove the link (Friends and Family in the example below). For example:

```
<nav id="menu-right">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>Friends</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Alexa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Alexander</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fred</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">James</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jefferson</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jordan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Meagan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Melissa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nicole</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Samantha</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Scott</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span>Family</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Adam</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ben</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bruce</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Eddie</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jack</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">John</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Martina</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Matthew</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Olivia</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Owen</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span>Work colleagues</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">David</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dennis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Eliza</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Larry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lisa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Michael</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rachelle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rick</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you.. **(UNTESTED)**

Create a file in your theme folder called nav-menu-walker.php and include this file in your theme functions.php file.

**nav-menu-walker.php**

```
class My_Nav_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args, $id = 0 ) {

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        if ( $args->has_children ) {

            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';

        } else {

            $item_output .= '<span>';
            $item_output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
            $item_output .= '</span>';         

        }

        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );     

    }

    function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output) {
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
        if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
            $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
        }
        return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }    

}
```

Then call your [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function with the walker.. e.g.

```
        <?php 
            wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'theme_location'    =>  'primary-menu',
                    'walker'            =>  new My_Nav_Menu_Walker()
                )
            ); 
        ?>
```

You may have to tweak the arguments to work with your theme obviously..

give that a go!

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I'll test it later today and report back.

Also, would you advise including the custom walker code by including a separate php file rather than including the code directly into functions.php file to keep it cleaner? Or is there a technical reason for this?

Comment: No worries, hopefully it should work, I had butchered it from another project I worked on before ... 
Erm.. Entirely up to you really about the file, Me, personally I would keep it separate but it is entirely up to you..

Comment: OK, just dropped it in and had some issues but gave your code a run down and saw that it was the wrong way around, it was wrapping the everything that DIDN'T have a child in the span tags. I changed that around and all good! Got a couple of styling bugs but I don't think they're related to the walker in anyway. Again, massive thanks!